# How can I stop Google from indexing embedded iframes?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot, iframe

I have iframe widgets of external sources embedded on my website. For some reason Google seems to be indexing the URLs of the iframes and showing 404 errors for such URLs in the Crawl Section of Google Webmaster Tools. How can I stop Google from doing that?

The URLs don't follow a pattern so I don't think I can use *robots.txt* for it. Would `rel="nofollow"` work for iframes?

Comment: You want `content="noindex, nofollow"` in the meta, not `rel="nofollow"` as that's for href links designed for outbound use only.

Comment: @bybe Would that stop only iframes from being index or the entire page? I want the page with the iframes to be indexed.

Comment: PROBLEM: if the iframe has no "src" and the htmlcode is embeded and the robot metatag is there
the WHOLE Page is not indexed
google finds a robot-meta tag in the html, regardless where :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *For some reason Google seems to be indexing the URLs of the iframes*

As covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en), Google will indeed try to crawl and `associate framed content with the page containing the frames`.

> *Would rel="nofollow" work for iframes?*

Within the header section of the iframe page (not the parent page *containing* the iframe), use:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

As explained by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag), this:

`instructs web crawlers to not index the page and to not crawl any of the links on the page.`

(If you just want to target the Googlebot and not other crawlers, then change `name="robots"` -> `name="googlebot"`)

Based on pretty extensive experience with iframes, I can confirm that this prevents iframe pages from being indexed, while still allowing the parent page containing the iframe to be indexed.

Comment: Something like `<iframe src="..."><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"></iframe>`?

Comment: Nope, that won't work. You'll need to place the `noindex, nofollow` meta tag in the _head_ section of the iframe page, not in the parent page containing the iframe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Could you please post an example?

Comment: See the first example in the link I provided from Google in my answer [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag). Use the robots meta tag from my answer the same way, in the source code of the _iframe_ page (i.e., the page you have `<iframe src=` set to).

Comment: How can I add the meta tags to source code for iframe if it is an external source? I'm not the owner of that iframe page and cannot edit it's content.

Comment: Your question didn't indicate that you don't have access to the source code of the iframe page/widget (which is why you received the comments and above answer). Google should not be crawling or indexing URLs for a different domain. If you're receiving `404` errors from _backlinks_ from another domain, then you can [disavow](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) those backlinks. Unless spammy or low-quality, `404` errors are not necessarily harmful and can be ignored.