# Is blocking googlebot from accessing portions of the site with robots.txt penalized by Google?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot

I was reading this [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page).
Let's say i have a div with something useful for users but i don't want it to be considered by Google.
If i put this on an iframe and block the googlebot with robots.txt so it won't read it. Would i be penalized?

Did google ever clarified it? Or maybe from experience someone can confirm it's alright to do, or not?

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77379/how-can-i-stop-google-from-indexing-embedded-iframes

Comment: Mine is a disqus recent comments widget not moderated and often things i don't want pop up in there and end up indexed. I need to stop it. I'm gonna try the noindex method on iframe. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

No your site will not penalize by search engine as many of the website also used such techniques or code where crawler are not able to crawl the area of the web page.
It is not the reason to penalize the Site or page.